# ISO20022 complains STANDARDS, -Testing AND PRODUCTION SETUP AS THE JDE PLATFORM for TESTING VERSIONS of transaction types of ISO20022 Standards,

Tags: stellar-core

We are WORKING on a Solution for MAPPING, TESTING, and MOVING APPROVED ISO20020 Version of Financial transitions to PRODUCTION, and also Monitoring the STATUS of each ISO 20022 TRANSACTIONS
using the JDE Processing Option, User Define Codes, Workflow Process.

My 10 years experience as a ISO Professional Data Mapper and Translator to any Format on Different types of Systems and Data formats using JDE any many other Mapping Application Translators, I have many concerns and questions, about the Implementation Procedures for the Different Versions which we will be testing and moving to Production, and all these Versions for each specific Transaction type needs to be Tested and Approved, also Rejection of Transactions because of Data Integrity of Invalid information mapped into the ISO 20022 Data format, to be solved immediately for reprocessing.

My question is are there any UTILITIES which will help to IMPORT and EXPORT, and the Mapping and Translation of the Information to ISO 20020 Format, validating syntax and then transmitting and tracking the Acknowledgment of the ASN, or which Processing status the ISO20020 Transaction is pending.

It is not simple as many Videos and Professionals have been explaining.